# What is the purpose of the plastic disk between the cassette and the rear wheel?

Tags: wheels, cassette, equipment

There's a plastic disc between the cassette and rear wheel on my bicycle. It doesn't seem to have any effect on the actual drivetrain; but I've seen it on a number of bicycles.

What is it for?

Comment: The spoke guard is there so that when your misadjusted/maltreated rear derailer shifts the chain off the top sprocket it doesn't jam in the spokes.  This is the difference between being simply annoyed and being thrown off the bike (and possibly damaging the wheel).

Comment: @Daniel: If only I had known to search for "spoke guard". On the other hand if I'd have known that I'd not have had to ask the question :)

Comment: I'm convince that its real purpose is to work itself loose and then to rattle around clunkily until it drives you nuts.

Comment: The plastic ones like to deform and start rubbing on the derailleur too...

Comment: The colloquial term is 'dork disk', which indicates how a lot of bikers view them.

Comment: For completeness - it was not uncommon to see steel or aluminium ones on road bikes in the 80s.

Comment: The plastic ones also become brittle and then unpleasantly disintegrate during a ride. The remains are then hard to remove but rattle really badly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_sp-ss.html#spokeprotector):

> **Spoke Protector**
>
> A plastic or sheet-metal disc that fits between the cluster and the right-side spokes of a rear wheel. This is intended to prevent the
>   derailer or chain from getting caught in the spokes, possibly causing
>   very extensive/expensive damage/destruction to the wheel, the
>   derailer, and the frame.
>
> A spoke protector is not a necessity on a bike that is well treated, because the derailer can't go into the spokes if it's
>   properly adjusted and if it is not bent. Bicycles which are subjected
>   to rough handling, however, are prone to getting the rear derailer
>   bashed in, and in such a case, the spoke protector can prevent very
>   serious damage.

And from purely personal anecdotal experience: I have a friend that doesn't like spoke protectors and has been pretty vocal about it. Faith would have it that a maladjusted XTR derailleur wrecked his wheel and destroyed itself. A spoke protector would have prevented just that.

Comment: Why would one want to remove it? I mean, it seems to be a pain in the ass to keep clean, but beyond that...

Comment: Plastic is considered to be ugly by some, especially after a few years of sun discoloration. Some people do it to save weight. The old chrome ones looked much better.

Comment: Its also considered uncool by some people (I've found this is typically road cyclists who like to get dressed up in their spandex suits and what not).

Comment: Yeah, mainly they're considered uncool.  As to discoloration, you can always buy a new one every few years.

Comment: And it might signal that you don't care or can adjust your derailleur properly because you need "protection".

Comment: @user1049697 - Or it might signal that you're prudent.

Comment: Dirt and pebble tends to stuck between it and the cassette, making it sometimes allmost immposible to pedal. This ugly chunk of plastic should be broken and removed right after the bike purchase.

Comment: @user1049697 derailleurs can get clobbered quite easily, including in bike sheds when you might not even know anything had happened.  And mine certainly came in handy on the first test ride after changing the cassette and chain.

Comment: I agree with @J-unior. If you treat your bike well and test changes to chain/cassette/derailleur on a repair stand instead of the road, it's an utterly useless, ugly chunk of crap. (I should add that on a mountain bike they make more sense since unseen damage is possible.)

Comment: *I agree with J-unior. If you treat your bike well and test changes to chain/cassette/derailleur on a repair stand instead of the road, it's an utterly useless,*  Until you happen to be climbing hard, and the chain drops off inside the largest cog when you shift because your frame is flexing.  So no, the claim "If you treat your bike well and test changes to chain/cassette/derailleur on a repair stand instead of the road, it's an utterly useless, ugly chunk of crap" is complete **bullhockey**.  Ragging on spoke protectors is just more Cat 6 MUP racer elitism.

Comment: @J-unior 'looking nice and clean' by not having that 'useless, ugly chunk of crap' will not save you when your stays flex and/or your RD hanger gets bent.

I always suggest to people to buy black-colored dork disks if the discoloration of translucent ones puts them off.

Comment: @GregoryLeo it's been almost 4 years since I have changed my RD hanger last time and I'm far from being accurate rider. IDK about road riding, but in modern MTB frames and derailleurs you are most likely to bash your derailleur than the hanger.

Comment: Having recently had an RD go into the back wheel even with such a disk, they're not a complete solution.  The disk smashed and the chain chewed up the spokes; I only just unclipped in time to get off when the back wheel and pedals locked up.

Comment: @J-unior That's on your case though. It's your choice if you want to remove your spoke guard, but what I don't like is this stigma that dork disks are 'bad', which forces starting riders to remove theirs in order to 'not look bad'. I also don't get your last sentence. your hanger never gets bashed. it's the RD being bashed that bends the hanger.

Comment: @ChrisH If I were you, I'd get the aluminum ones. Another alternative that aggressive downhillers do is to insert a large cog on the freehub body before placing the cassette to act as a 'chainguide' and block the chain from slipping further in.
Heck, even some downhill drivetrains have cassettes with built-in AL dork disks.

Comment: @GregoryLeo I've never seen aluminium ones, but as I'm rebuilding the wheel tomorrow I'm hoping to fit a plastic one from a beater bike.

Comment: @ChrisH just cut out one from a 3mm delrin or PVC sheet. It's sturdier than the flimsy, nylon protectors.

Comment: @GregoryLeo 2mm polycarbonate ought to do the trick and I've got a piece just about the right size

Answer (score 3):

The other reason for the guard is to help keep chain oil off the brake disc.  Once the pads are fouled with oil the brake is useless. Sloppy oiling of the chain can cause a spray of oil droplets to migrate to the disc more easily then you might think. The guard does help prevent this.
It’s worth keeping it on the bike if you have rear disc brakes. And oil conservatively, slowly turning the crank for a bit then wipe off excess oil before riding.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Can you explain how chain lube would migrate sideways onto the rotor?  I've certainly had to wipe lube off the rim (rim brakes) when I got a bit over-enthusiastic, but I've never had it spread horizontally!

Comment: Welcome to the site - thank you for your answer.  Please do take a moment to browse the [tour] and learn how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

Its a spoke guard. It prevents the chain from going between the spokes and cassette causing damage if you shift too far. This can only happen on badly tuned gears or old friction shifted shifters.

Comment: Erm, I would hope that a friction shifter wouldn't be adjusted such that this would be necessary...

Comment: Even when using a friction shifter, you still have the high and low limit stops which prevent you from throwing the chain into the gears. Accidents happen though.

Answer (score -1):

It's a dork disk.

It's called that because a lot of cyclists are dorks and therefore remove the disk. Eventually, due to rear derailleur damage, the rear derailleur gets out of adjustment and causes the chain to get between the spinning wheel spokes and the stationary cassette. You get spoke damage that way.

In contrast, non-dork cyclists have a completely different approach: they not only leave the dork disk there, but also buy these disks for self-built wheels. One disk doesn't cost much but can prevent lot of damage due to chain getting between the spokes and the cassette.